# Find area given two curves which belong to the orthogonal family to $x^2+2y^2=K$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, area

**Calculate the region area of the $xy$-plane limited by curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ with $|x|\leq4$, knowing that $C_1$ passes through $(1, 1)$, $C_2$ passes through $(1, -1)$ and both curves belong to the orthogonal family a $x^2+2y^2=K$, with $K$ arbitrary constant.**

---

I did this:

$$\begin{matrix}
\mathfrak F:&2x+4yy'=0&(1)\\\\
\mathfrak F^\perp:&2x-4\dfrac y{y'}=0&(2)\\\\
\mathfrak F^\perp:&x=2\dfrac y{y'}&(3)\\\\
\mathfrak F^\perp:&\dfrac{y'}y=\dfrac2x&(4)\\\\
\mathfrak F^\perp:&\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\text dy}y=2\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\text dx}x&(5)\\\\
\mathfrak F^\perp:&\ln|y|=\ln(x^2)+C&(6)\\\\
\mathfrak F^\perp:&y=kx^2.&(7)
\end{matrix}$$

As we have $y(1)=1$ for $C_1$ and $y(1)=-1$ for $C_2$ then $$\begin{matrix}
C_1:&y=x^2\\
C_2:&y=-x^2,\\
\end{matrix}$$ so the integral for $|x|\leq4$ becomes $$\text{Area}=\dfrac{256}3,$$ according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area+between+x%5E2+and+-x%5E2+from+x+%3D+-4+to+x+%3D+4).

**Is this correct?** By the way I am not sure if the first steps are correct, because when I derive in the first equation $K$ dissapears (I know this is a constant, but sometimes we need to replace $x^2+2y^2=K$ inside the $\mathfrak F$, and this time that did not happen).

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: @amd when I plot $x^2+2y^2=K$ with the condition $y(1)=1,-1$ then $K=3$ so the ellipse becomes $x^2+2y^2=3$, and graphing this curve with $y=x^2$ and $y=-x^2$ I noticed that, in $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$, the curves are orthogonal. Please see this [image](https://imgur.com/a/CLmgDJS). What am I doing wrong? How would you solve it?

Comment: @amd ok. But if a family of curves with $y'$ then for find the orthogonal family we need to replace $y'$ with $-1/y'$, so that is what I did between steps $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake of my own. The orthogonal curves are indeed parabolas. I’ll note that the $y$-axis is also an orthogonal curve to the family of ellipses, but can’t be expressed in the form $y=kx^2$. Consolidating the two constants of integration eliminates a solution to the differential equation, fortunately not an issue for this particular problem.

Comment: @amd no problem, the experts also have mistakes `:)`. So, how is my work?

Comment: Seems fine to me. Did you really have to turn to W|A to integrate $2x^2$?

Comment: @amd I was lazy, then I realized the symmetry of the integral... `:')`. Big thaaaanks!